# How to update checkbox field and option field in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can update `text` field of a `form` but i can not update `checkbox` field,`option` field and `file` field in Laravel 5.2. I i going to update then i can see all text value is perfectly shown in update blade view but in option field, checkbox field i see it is default value its don't comes from database. Again if i update with another option then its not saving.What i have tried so far:

**My Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id=0)
{
    //
    $id = $request->input("id");
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->product_name = $request->input('product_name');
    $product->product_storage = $request->input('product_storage');
    $product->product_percentage = $request->input('product_percentage');
    $product->can_draw = $request->input('can_draw');
    $product->real_price = $request->input('real_price');
    $product->product_image = $request->input('product_image');

    $product->save();

    $request->session()->flash('alert-info', 'Product Successfully Updated!'); 
    return Redirect::to('admin/product/all');
}
```

**My update.blade.php View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">{{ trans('common.can_be_draw') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="input-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <select name="can_draw" class="form-control">
                <option value="{{ $product->can_draw }}">{{ trans('common.open') }}open</option>
                <option value="{{ $product->can_draw }}">{{ trans('common.close') }}close</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    </div>                      
</div>                      
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">{{ trans('common.real_prize') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="input-icon">

            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="real_price" value="{{ $product->real_price }}"> {{ trans('common.yes') }}yes 
            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="real_price" value="{{ $product->real_price }}" checked="checked"> {{ trans('common.no') }}no
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile" class="col-md-3 control-label">{{ trans('common.product_picture') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="product_image" value="{{ $product->product_image }}">
        <small>{{ trans('common.pic_summery') }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the difficulty you are facing

Comment: @Rohitshah i have updated my question. Please see and answered if you can.

Comment: You are passing same values in your option and radio field so you are saving the same values in db thats the reason it is not getting updated

Comment: so you cant save the can_draw value?

Comment: @Rohitshah understand. But i want when anyone going to update any product then all value will retrieve from database and show. For text field all value retrieve perfectly but for checkbox and option field its always selected same value. But it should be from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
   <input type="radio" {{$product->can_draw == 'Yes' ? 'checked' : ''}} class="form-control" name="real_price" value="Yes"> {{ trans('common.yes') }}yes 
   <input type="radio" {{$product->can_draw == 'Yes' ? '' : 'checked'}} class="form-control" name="real_price" value="No" > {{ trans('common.no') }}no
```

> EDIT

I have edited the above*

You should change the value to Yes and No and use this to check if the `value` saved is `Yes` or `No`. It does not matter how much is `real_price`

Comment: It always checked `yes` though in database its `no`. And `{{$product->can_draw ? 'checked' : ''}}` this should be `{{$product->real_price ? 'checked' : ''}}`

Comment: field name is `name="real_price"` thats why you must retrieve from `{{$product->real_price == 'Yes' ? 'checked' : ''}}` . Thanks now its working.

Answer (score 1):

your option field have same value ({{ $product->can_draw }})

```
 <option value="value1"{{( $product->can_draw=='value1'?selected)}}>{{ trans('common.open') }}open</option>
<option value="value2 " {{( $product->can_draw=='value1'?selected)}}>{{ trans('common.close') }}close</option>
```

and for file field must use file not input:

```
$product->product_image = $request->file('product_image');
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' ` . I this won't be a solution of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just can save option value by requesting from select name.
In your example: 
       `select name = "can_draw"`
Just save value from request:

```
$product->can_draw = $request->can_draw;
```

For checkbox same:

```
$product->real_price = $request->real_price;
```

Not necessary indicate input() helper in request.

To retrieve all value for option and check box value, please use foreach methods:

```
@foreach($can_draws as $can_draw)
 <option value="{{ $can_draw->id }}">{{ $can_draw->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```